# Getting "Cannot read property prompt of undefined" from one provider to another

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-providers

**alert-service.ts**

```
 public Alert = {
        prompt: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Enter username',
              inputs: [
                {
                  name: 'username',
                  placeholder: 'Username'
                },
              ],
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Cancel',
                  handler: data => {
                    reject(false);
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Save',
                  handler: data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve(data);
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
            prompt.present();
          });
        }
      }
```

**request-service.ts**

```
function () {
    this.prompt.Alert.prompt().then((res) => {
           this.user.username = res;
           alert(this.user.username);
    }, err => {
          this.alertService.Alert.alert('user_cancelled', 'Error');
    }); 
}
```

*This runs in the browser when I use IONIC Serve, but it's not working on a device.*
I'm getting **Can not read property 'prompt' of undefined**

Comment: Don't use `function () {` in your `request-service.ts` It should br either arrow function or method

Answer (score 0):

When you type that

```
function () {
    this.prompt.Alert.prompt().then((res) => {
          this.user.username = res;
          alert(this.user.username);
    }, err => {
          this.alertService.Alert.alert('user_cancelled', 'Error');
    }); 
}
```

You don't use the Typescript fat arrow function. If you don't want to use fat arrows, you have to **use Javascript closures to get the right context for the `this` keyword**.

Right now, the `this` keyword is referencing your function, not your object.

**EDIT** Example for closures :

In a typescript class :

```
x = 'Hey baby';
let fatArrowFunction= () => console.log(this.x); // "Hey baby"
that = this;
let usualFunction = function() {
  let x = 'Hey sweetheart';
  console.log(x); // "Hey sweethearth"
  console.log(this.x); // "Hey sweethearth"
  console.log(that.x); // "Hey baby"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example what you mean?

Comment: I couldn't' understand what u meant. can you explain in the code that I wrote?

Comment: simply replace `function()` with `myFunction = () =>`